# Grouping a set of numbers

Tags: factoring, clustering

I have a *set* of numbers which I don´t know if they belong to the same *group* (I could also call it *factor* or *treatment*, but actually each *group* is suppose to identify the same biological event).

I am assuming that this *set* can contain numbers belonging to 1 or more *groups*. I am going to compute several *sets* of numbers and for the majority of them I would expect just 1 *group*. Moreover, in the majority of the *sets* which have more than 1 *group* they are expected to have no more than 5 *groups*.

I am aware that this question can be very cloudy, however, I`am looking for some advice to at least read more about some specific mathematical topic that could help me in the purpose.

Let´s try to give a very simplified example.
Imaginary `set 1`:

```
set1 <- c(2000, 2500, 2400, 3600, 1500)
```

Imaginary `set 2`:

```
set2 <- c(1000, 1400, 3800, 1200, 3700)
```

Here I could expect something like 3 *groups* to `set 1`: *group* 1 : 2000, 2500, 2400 **and** *group* 2: 3600 **and** *group* 3: 1500.

To the `set 2` I would expect two *groups*: *group* 1 : 1000, 1400, 1200 **and** *group* 2 : 3800, 3700.

Comment: At least for me, it is not very clear what the question is. But I'm almost sure that it is not about graph theory.

Comment: Hard to follow.  Can you give us an example?  You might look up "Clustering" on line...algorithms that sometimes tell you if part of a data set is "clustered" around some point or other.  Perhaps that is relevant, I'm not sure.

Comment: Please check the update, but anyway I would be pleased to give more information.